# What to do when edit is only 1 very important character change

Tags: discusión, ediciones

[image]

The post is fine as is, except for the missing accent.

What to do?  Do higher rep users/mods have a way around this restriction? Should I flag?

Comment: You can make some stylistic improvements. Here, simply by adding some bullet points your edit would have been accepted. I've been there, and I've been forced to make silly changes like substituting a `_` for a `*` to format italics so my edit would be accepted. It may be a pain in the ass, but on the other hand six characters aren't that many characters. There's always something you can improve, and if not, just add a comment to the post and delete it once the OP has edited it so there's not unnecessary "noise" in the comments section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a flag is warranted in this case.

What I would do is comment to the OP and tell him about the simple mistake. He can then edit it himself with freedom.

Users with higher rep can also edit it this way AFAIK